Is $L^2(\Omega) =L^\infty(\Omega)$ for bounded domains?
Is it true that a function $f$ on a bounded domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is $L^2$ if and only if it is $L^\infty$ on that domain?
Suppose $f\in L^2$
then $f^2$ is integrable, so it is finite on sets of positive measure. So its essential supremum is finite, right?
Suppose $f\in L^\infty$
so it has a finite essential supremum, so i can estimate it
$$\text{ess sup} f \leq g \text{ a.e.}$$
for a constant function $g$ that i just define as the essential sup of $f$:
$$g:= \text{ess sup} f$$
and $g$ is just a constant function of finite value over a bounded domain which is $L^2$, right?
I have a feeling that $L^2(\Omega) \neq L^\infty(\Omega)$, so where is my mistake?

why the downvote ? - this is a perfectly clear question about real analysis, a topic that is difficult due to the large number of non-obvious counter examples and special cases lots of theorems have. this question is precisely about one of them.

Consider $x^{1/4}$ in $(0,1)$. Then this is in $L^2$ but not bounded.

Check $f(x) = x^{\tfrac{1}{4}}$ for $\Omega = (0, 1)$.

Do you both mean $x^{-1/4}$?


… so it is finite on sets of positive measure

First of all, $f\in L^2$ implies it is a.e real-valued (rather than extended-real-valued), so what you meant to say is

… so it is bounded on sets of positive measure

But still this is the erroneous statement. No matter how much you try to fix it (e.g ‘for every set of positive measure $P$, there is a measure zero subset’ $Z\subset P$ such that $f$ is bounded on $P\setminus Z$’), it is still false in general. The counterexample is given in the comments already: $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^{1/4}}$ on $(0,1)$, or really $f_{\alpha}(x)=:\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$ on $(0,1)$ with $\alpha<\frac{1}{2}$.
Whenever you deal with questions about $L^p$ spaces and their inclusions, the first few things to always look at are the functions $f_{\alpha}(x)=\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$ in the respective regions $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$. This simple collection of functions from single variable calculus contains lots of insight!
